# Transparent list item in Windows Store app

Tags: css, windows-store-apps

I would like my list items in my ListView to be transparent.

I tried this, but it does nnot work, any tips?

HTML:

```
<section aria-label="Main content" role="main">
        <div id="listItemTemplate" data-win-control="WinJS.Binding.Template">
            <div class="listItem">
                <div class="listItemTemplate-Detail">
                    <h4 data-win-bind="innerText: label"></h4>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="listView" data-win-control="WinJS.UI.ListView" data-win-options="{itemDataSource : DataExample.itemList.dataSource, itemTemplate: select('#listItemTemplate'), layout: {type: WinJS.UI.GridLayout}}"></div>
    </section>
```

CSS:

```
.listItem {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24);
}
.win-listview .win-container {
    background-color:transparent !important;
}
```

Background is correctly set, but it is not transparent.

And the validator in VS give me this error:

> Validation (CSS 3.0): "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)" is not a valid value for
>   the "background-color" property.

I thought this was valid CSS3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that another class was blocking my CSS `win-itembox`.

```
.win-listview .win-container .win-itembox {
    background-color:rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);
}
```